# How to find topology supervisor using command line

Tags: command-line, apache-storm

Using storm UI we can find a supervisor for a particular active topology but how do we find the same information using only command line?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the CLI has a command that lets you get the supervisors, but if not you can try the Storm UI REST API http://storm.apache.org/releases/1.2.0/STORM-UI-REST-API.html (use curl or similar).